# Not able to Login once user has been created in Django admin

Tags: django, authentication

I am able to create the user with permissions and groups. But I am not able to login with the created user in django admin.[Creation of the user and permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YFhJ.png)

Comment: Why does your password field contains a password hash? Can you share the modeladmin you used?

Comment: *I have used create method before saving the data.*

def create(self, validated_data):
        if ('password' in validated_data) and (validated_data['password'] is not None):
            password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        else:
            password = make_password(validated_data['username'])
        permissions = validated_data['permissions']
        validated_data.pop('permissions')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.permissions.set(permissions)
        user.save()
        return user

Answer (score 0):

For a user to be able to login in django admin portal, `is_staff` field needs to be checked/marked as true.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should set user as **is_staff** and **is_superuser**

Then you can login with the account.

In addition, you can change the appearance of django admin with code below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import User
# Register your models here.

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets  = (
        ('Login Details', {
            'fields': ('username', 'password')
        }),

        ('Informations', {
            'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email','phonenumber')
        }),

        ('Permissions', {
            'fields': (
                'is_active',
                'is_staff',
                'is_superuser',
                'groups',
                'user_permissions'
            )
        }),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Login Details', {
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2','phonenumber')
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I want the user to be student (without staff, and superuser). is it possible to have???

Comment: For this one you should make a Group with this permission or add a Admin Permistion for a student. Go to Permissions section and add permission to user. However, I think you should give him/her is_staff permission then moderate the permissions.

Comment: ok fine.

I have created a group with 0 permissions and added to the user while creating user. so as per the permissions that user should not do any operations since no permissions has been enabled right? But I am able to do that... can you please help me to fix it

Comment: Yes, but why you need student access to django admin?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to create a *superuser* to be able login admin panel, **python manage.py createsuperuser**.